# Can't downgrade RestSharp

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, restsharp

Trying to downgrade RestSharp to 105.1.0 from 105.2.3 but can't. Staying with the newest version works fine and installs fine.

`Install-Package RestSharp -Version 105.1.0`

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'RestSharp.105.1.0' with respect to project 'project.iOS', targeting 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'RestSharp.105.1.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'RestSharp.105.1.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'RestSharp.105.1.0'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'RestSharp.105.1.0' does not exist in project 'project.iOS'
Package 'RestSharp.105.1.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\....project\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'RestSharp 105.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package RestSharp -Version 105.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

`Install-Package RestSharp`

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'RestSharp.105.2.3' with respect to project 'project.iOS', targeting 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'RestSharp.105.2.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'RestSharp.105.2.3'
Resolved actions to install package 'RestSharp.105.2.3'
Package 'RestSharp.105.2.3' already exists in folder 'C:\Users\...\project\packages'
Added package 'RestSharp.105.2.3' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'RestSharp 105.2.3' to project.iOS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the NuGet package, the answer will be very clear.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/105.1.0

Unzip the `.nupkg` and go to the `lib` folder

You will see the respective targets allowed here. Notice there is not target for `Xamarin.iOS10` or `MonoTouch10` anywhere in the 105.1.0 NuGet package.

However if you do the same to

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/105.2.3

You will see there are targets for `Xamarin.iOS10` and `MonoTouch10`.

Comment: So how can I fix that and downgrade to `105.1`?

Comment: You can't really fix this. This is something missing in the previous library.